# Logic inside combining algebraic operations into vector-matrix form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

[The derivative of a matrix-valued function with respect to a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530333/the-derivative-of-a-matrix-valued-function-with-respect-to-a-matrix/)

[Chain rule and vector-matrix calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531094/chain-rule-and-vector-matrix-calculus/)

Fundamental object with which we will work:

$x=[a,b,c]^T$ - $3 \times 1$ vector

Now let's keep in mind an important properties:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x \cdot x^T)=x \otimes I + I \otimes x$

$(A \otimes B)v=vec(BVA^T)$

Let's take expression:

$q_1=x \cdot x^T \cdot x$

Let's find the derivatives with respect to the components of the vector $x$ separately. We get a series of terms:

$\frac{d}{da}q_1=\frac{d}{da}x \cdot x^T \cdot x + x \cdot \frac{d}{da}x^T \cdot x + x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{da}x$

$\frac{d}{db}q_1=\frac{d}{db}x \cdot x^T \cdot x + x \cdot \frac{d}{db}x^T \cdot x + x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{db}x$

$\frac{d}{dc}q_1=\frac{d}{dc}x \cdot x^T \cdot x + x \cdot \frac{d}{dc}x^T \cdot x + x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{dc}x$

Now let's try to combine these expressions into one vector-matrix form:

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{d}{da}x \cdot x^T \cdot x \\ \frac{d}{db}x \cdot x^T \cdot x \\ \frac{d}{dc}x \cdot x^T \cdot x \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow x^T \cdot x \cdot I$

$\begin{bmatrix} x \cdot \frac{d}{da}x^T \cdot x \\ x \cdot \frac{d}{db}x^T \cdot x \\ x \cdot \frac{d}{dc}x^T \cdot x  \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow x \cdot x^T$

$\begin{bmatrix} x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{da}x \\ x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{db}x \\ x \cdot x^T \cdot \frac{d}{dc}x  \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow x \cdot x^T$

Thus, the resulting expression will look like:

$\frac{d}{dx}q_1=x^T \cdot x \cdot I + 2 \cdot x \cdot x^T$

**My question is this:** as long as we work with the individual components of the vector, the dot product in the expression is preserved + we use the chain rule. Is there any logic/rule/algorithm for combining such simple terms into one vector matrix operation? When does the transition from the scalar product to the Kronecker product, etc., occur?

Comment: Are you aware of this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\d{\delta}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The derivative of a vector $x$ with respect to its $k^{th}$ component is the $k^{th}$ cartesian basis vector, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{x}{x_k} &= e_k \\
}$$
Taking the $i^{th}$ component of this equation produces the result in *index notation*
$$\eqalign{
e_i^T\gradLR{x}{x_k} &= e_i^Te_k \qiq \grad{x_i}{x_k} = \d_{ik}
\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
Applying these results to the matrix $\,xx^T$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\,(xx^T)}{x_k} &= xe_k^T + e_kx^T  \qiq
\grad{\,(x_ix_j)}{x_k} &= x_i\d_{jk} + \d_{ik}x_j \\
}$$
So the gradient of the matrix $xx^T$ with respect to the vector $x$ is a third-order tensor (which is why it carries 3 free indexes)
which **cannot** be rendered in *matrix notation*.

So your first "important property" is simply not true. The result that you've misquoted is actually
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\vc{xx^T}}{x} &= {x\otimes I + I\otimes x}  \\
}$$
You may not think the presence of that $\vc{}$ operator is important, but it is.

Comment: Greg, I've sorted out some of the details, but I still need help with "packing". Check out the thread please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546317/kronecker-product-packing-logic